# What is the basin of attraction of the Dottie Number?

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points, basins-of-attraction

I know that the sole real solution to $\cos x = x$, which I'll call $\textbf{d}$, is a universal attractor of the cosine function for all the real numbers. Meaning that:

$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R} \left(\lim_{n\to\infty} \underbrace{\cos\circ\cos\circ\cdots\circ\cos}_{n\text{ iterations}}\ x=\textbf{d}\right)$$

I also know that this is true for some subset of $\mathbb{C}$. But what is that subset? How would I find that subset? How would I even prove the above for the real numbers?

Comment: So, you want the Julia set for the cosine?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof in the real case that the basin of attraction of $d$ for $\cos$ is the whole real line.

$\cos\circ\cos$ maps the real line to the interval $I=[\cos(1),1] \supseteq [0.53,1] \ni d \approx 0.739085$.

The derivative of $\cos$ in $I$ ranges in $[\sin(\cos(1),\sin(1)] \subseteq [0.52,0.85] \subset [0,1)$.

Thus, $\cos$ is a contraction in $I$ and so $I$ is contained in the basin of attraction of $\cos$. Therefore, so is the whole real line.